# Edit the x limits of least squares line

Tags: matlab, regression, least-squares

I created two scatter plots and then used lsline to add regression lines for each plot. I used this code:

```
for i=1:2
  x = ..;
  y = ..;
  scatter(x, y, 50, 'MarkerFaceColor',myColours(i, :));
end
h_lines = lsline;
```

However, the darker line extends far beyond the last data point in that scatter plot (which is at around x=0.3):

[image]

lsline doesn't seem to have properties that allow its horizontal range to be set. Is there a workaround to set this separately for the two lines, in Matlab 2016a?

Comment: Can you share the code you used to generate and plot these?

Comment: ok, will edit my question now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## For a single data set

This is a workaround rather than a solution. `lsline` internally calls `refline`, which plots a line filling the axis **as given by their current limits** (`xlim` and `ylim`). So you can change those limits to the extent you want for the line, call `lsline`,  and then restore the limits.

Example:

```
x = randn(1,100);
y = 2*x + randn(1,100); % random, correlated data
plot(x, y, '.') % scatter plot
xlim([-1.5 1.5]) % desired limit for line
lsline % plot line
xlim auto % restore axis limit
```

[image]

## For several data sets

In this case you can apply the same procedure for each data set sequentially, but you need to **keep only one data set visible** when you call `lsline`; otherwise when you call it to create the second line it will also create a new version of the first (with the wrong range).

Example:

```
x = randn(1,100); y = 2*x + randn(1,100); % random, correlated data
h = plot(x, y, 'b.'); % scatter plot
axis([min(x) max(x) min(y) max(y)]) % desired limit for line
lsline % plot line
xlim auto % restore axis limit
hold on
x = 2*randn(1,100) - 5; y = 1.2*x + randn(1,100) + 6; % random, correlated data
plot(x, y, 'r.') % scatter plot
axis([min(x) max(x) min(y) max(y)]) % desired limit for line
set(h, 'HandleVisibility', 'off'); % hide previous plot
lsline % plot line
set(h, 'HandleVisibility', 'on'); % restore visibility
xlim auto % restore axis limit
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But does this work when I have two different sets of points? The xlim just sets a range for both whereas I'd like each regression line to have its own range of x values

Answer (score 4):

Yet another solution: implement your own `hsline`. It's easy!

In MATLAB, doing a least squares fit of a straight line is trivial. Given column vectors `x` and `y` with `N` elements, `b = [ones(N,1),x] \ y;` are the parameters to the best fit line. `[1,x1;1,x2]*b` are the y locations of two points along the line with x-coordinates `x1` and `x2`. Thus you can write (following [Luis' example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55906433/7328782), and getting the exact same output):

```matlab
N = 100;
x = randn(N,1); y = 2*x + randn(N,1); % random, correlated data
h = plot(x, y, 'b.'); % scatter plot
hold on
b = [ones(N,1),x] \ y;
x = [min(x);max(x)];
plot(x,[ones(2,1),x] * b, 'b-')

x = 2*randn(N,1) - 5; y = 1.2*x + randn(N,1) + 6; % random, correlated data
plot(x, y, 'r.') % scatter plot
b = [ones(N,1),x] \ y;
x = [min(x);max(x)];
plot(x,[ones(2,1),x] * b, 'r-')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the points that define the line using

```
h_lines =lsline;
```

`h_lines(ii).XData` and `h_lines(ii).YData` will contain 2 points that define the lines for each `ii=1,2` line. Use those to create en equation of a line, and plot the line in the range you want.

Comment: actually `h` in that case will be an array of `line` object. He will first have to find which of them is to be adjusted ...

Comment: Ander, do you mean lsline rather than hsline?!

Comment: @z8080 was a typo

Comment: One that has caught on, though, judging by subsequent answers here ;)